# MySQL 'Between' dates not selecting the correct results using PHP (and Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code (using CodeIgniter):

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');

$then = strtotime($now . '-1 week');

$then = date('Y-m-d', $then);

$q3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
                          FROM posts 
                         WHERE publish_date BETWEEN '$then' AND '$now'");

$data['posts_today'] = $q3->num_rows();
```

I clearly have posted at least twenty posts this week, but it only displays '1'. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: what if you perform the same query in mysql console or PMA?

Comment: In console it still just returns one result row.

Comment: Well, then it is just one row in that time interval. Btw, why won't you show us the plain sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
$q3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
                          FROM posts 
                         WHERE publish_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
                                                AND NOW()");
```

Potential issues I see:

- is `POSTS.publish_date` a DATETIME data type?
- if PHP and MySQL are on different hosts, NOW from codeigniter/PHP could be a different time than what's being stored/used in MySQL.

Comment: POSTS.publish_date is a DATETIME, but that solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that MySQL expects dates in that format. You might be better off using MySQL's date functions to compose them.

Answer (score 0):

First, offload everything you can to MySQL.  The less date math you have to do the better.

Second, Look at what your actual created code looks like.  Change this

```
$q3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
                      FROM posts 
                     WHERE publish_date BETWEEN '$then' AND '$now'");
```

to this

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
                      FROM posts 
                     WHERE publish_date BETWEEN '$then' AND '$now'");
print "EXECUTING: $sql\n";
$q3 = $this->db->query( $sql );
```

You're assuming that the SQL you are generating is valid, and it might not be.  This is very common when you're using one language to generate code in another.  Always `print` to verify your assumptions.